# How to calculate Lost customer power bi based on previous month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have that code in order to find how much customers I lost from previous month (it's working, but because all months are not equal, it give me small error %  ) :

the churn time rate is a number of days 30 or 31 with a slice
but i don't want to change manually , there is a way to filter directly with previousmonth() ?

```
Lost pat = 
VAR PATnew= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Requête datas'[PAT_SEQ_NO]),
FILTER(ALL(Calendrier[Date]),
Calendrier[Date]>MIN(Calendrier[Date])- 'Churn time rate jours'[Valeur Churn time rate]))
VAR PriorPAt=CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Requête datas'[PAT_SEQ_NO]),
FILTER(ALL(Calendrier[Date]),
Calendrier[Date]>MIN(Calendrier[Date])))
Return
COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(PATnew,PriorPAt))
```

thanks you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can get previous numbers by creating measure > `PreviousMonth(date_column)`function.

Something  like - `Last month count = CALCULATE(count(Sale[Sales]),PREVIOUSMONTH('sale'[Date_Column]))`